# GNAT GPS Project Explorer View is Missing

Tags: gnat

I am using GNAT GPS version 6.0.1 in Windows 7. For some unknown reason, the Project View pane that is on the left side of the main window has disappeared when I use the debugger. I can't find any menu or preference options that control whether this pane is visible.

Update--
I should point out that this is the pane with the tabs along the left side rather than along the top. I can show a similar pane with projects listed by splitting the main window, but its tabs are along the top. Also, Its behavior is different form the one with tabs on the left side. Double-clicking on a file name, for example, should open the file in the main window. Using a split window. this opens the file in the window that is showing the projects.
End of Update --

I can select Project -> Project View from the toolbar, and I get a Project View as one tab in the main window (along with the source files that I am working with).

Can someone tell me how to control whether the left-hand pane is visible and how to make sure the Project View has a tab in that pane?

Also, when I look at Window -> Perspective, I see that the Default perspective is selected when I'm not using the debugger and the Debug perspective is selected when I am using the debugger. Switching from the Debug perspective to the Default perspective while I am running the debugger does bring back the left-hand pane, but my debug tab and the Debugger Data window disappear. Can I fix the Debug perspective so the left-hand pane is part of its configuration by deffault?

By the way, in this version, there is no Show View option in the toolbar menus.

Answer (score 0):

This can be opened with /Project/Project View or /Tools/Views/Project.
To put the tabs to the left instead of the top, right click on the tab and select the Tabs Location item. You can also use drag-and-drop (from a tab) to move windows around, in particular to move the Project view to the left of your desktop.
That said, the simplest might be to remove the file $HOME/.gps/perspectives6.xml to restart from the default desktop.